# Nodemailer Won't Mail On Exit

Tags: node.js, email, events, nodemailer

In my script, I want to send an email with data about a script's run using Nodemailer. The same `transporter` is used in the middle of the script and I successfully send emails. However, the same code inside an exit event handler simply doesn't do anything. No email, no "Report Sent!" output to console, although I do get the output to console of the `mailOption` variable. Assuming maybe the async operation wasn't being completed before exiting, I added a temporary delay step to verify this. Still no email produced. Am I doing something wrong?

```
function exitHandler(er) {
  end = moment().utc();

  // report template
  var tplPath = path.resolve('report.html');
  var juiceFileDeAsync = deasync(juice.juiceFile);
  var tpl = juiceFileDeAsync(tplPath, { webResources: {images: false} });
  var email = nunjucks.renderString(tpl, {
    startDate: start.format("MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"),
    duration: end.diff(start,'seconds'),
    report: sentEmails,
    warns: warns,
    errors: errors
  });
  // email report
  mailOptions.to = '<valid email>';
  mailOptions.html = email;
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info) {
    console.log('Report sent!', error, info);
  });
  console.log(mailOptions);
  if (er) {
    console.log(er);
  }

  var e = new Date().getTime() + (10 * 1000);
  while (new Date().getTime() <= e) {
    ;
  }

}

// do something when app is closing
process.on('exit', exitHandler);
process.on('uncaughtException', exitHandler);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://nodejs.org/api/process.html
Take a look at the Event: exit documentation:

```
process.on('exit', function(code) {
    // do *NOT* do this
    setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('This will not run');
    }, 0);
    console.log('About to exit with code:', code);
});
```

> once all exit listeners have finished running the process will exit. Therefore you must only perform synchronous operations in this handler.

Comment: I guess I misread. I thought async ops would be queued and if they ran before the handler fully exited, then they would run before the process ended. As such, the delay would ensure the async op would complete before fully exiting. Is there an actual "block" on async operations then? If so, any library that send emails synchronously?

Comment: Even process.nextTick won't fire (just tested). I cannot recommend synchronous email clients for node ... network/socket ops are async again. you could try to write a file in sync, and use cron to periodically check the file and re-send via email.